# Qt to update (repaint) textbox while processing

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, qt5, qwidget

My Qt 4 application can only update the log box area (actually the whole GUI) until a function finishes execution. Is there any way to update the GUI/log box during the execution? Like adding something like `QWidget::repaint()` or `QWidget::update()` in the for loop, so the user can see that the GUI is processing, rather than wait until the function finishes and print out the log at once.

Answer (score 2):

You need to occasionally call [`QCoreApplication::processEvents()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) during the execution of your function. This will keep the GUI alive and responsive by letting the event loop run.

An alternative is to execute your function in a separate thread. More information on threads in Qt can be found here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads.html.